# How to do more than one substring replace at once in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, replace

I have a directory contains image files that are to be echoed in bash. While echoing, I want to replace both file name and extension in single line command.

Example files:

```
images/file_name_1.jpg
images/file_name_2.jpg
```

Normally, I can do single replacement like this:

```bash
for i in images/*; do echo ${i/file/image}; done
```

And the output becomes like:

```bash
images/image_name_1.jpg
images/image_name_2.jpg
```

How can I keep it in for loop and replace the "jpg" string to "png" also? It's just an instance, I could replace the dot to comma etc.

When I try this:

```bash
for i in images/*; do echo ${{i/jpg/png}/file/image}; done
```

It doesn't work. I coulnd't find any other solution or idea. Is this possible -if so, how?

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work in bash, but nested replacements do work just like you expected in zsh. Depending on your environment you might consider using a better shell ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple approach would be to assign the result to a variable, then work with that variable. Example:

```bash
for filename in images/*
do
    echo "filename is now $filename"
    filename=${filename/jpg/png}; echo "filename is now $filename"
    filename=${filename/file/image}; echo "filename is now $filename"
    echo "final filename is ${filename}"
done
```

Comment: This answer is not complete. the substitutions will apply anywhere in the filename strings. Based on the question, Kubilay wants to replace a prefix and an extension (suffix). can you modify and take this into consideration:
${var/#Pattern/Replacement}

    If prefix of var matches Pattern, then substitute Replacement for Pattern.
${var/%Pattern/Replacement}

    If suffix of var matches Pattern, then substitute Replacement for Pattern.

Comment: @rMistero There's no rule against posting another answer just because an answer has been accepted. In fact, I think you should, especially since the semantics of what you are proposing are different. That said, this is the way to do what the OP said having tried, so even if there are other results that could also be valid, I believe it is safe to assume that this is in line with what the OP wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the previous replacement to a variable and run replace on that variable instead

```bash
for i in images/*
do
    j=${i/jpg/png}
    echo ${j/file/image}
done
```

Comment: Not sure if it works. "for i in images/*; do j={i/jpg/png} echo ${j/file/image}; done" echoes "{i/jpg/png}" repeatedly.

Comment: Now yes: "for i in images/*.jpg; do j=${i/jpg/png}; echo ${j/file/image}; done". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to change *any string*:

```
$ echo "images/file_name_1.jpg" | perl -pE 's/file/image/;s/jpg$/png/;'
images/image_name_1.png
```

a shortcut to rename (which may be the ultimate goal:

```
$ rename 's/file/image/;s/jpg$/png/;' "$i"
```

Comment: I still think invoking Perl once for each file is overkill, but at least now this gives an answer to the question. :)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You don't need to invoke Perl for each file, you can do `rename … images/*`. But this requires a Debian-based distribution (`rename` on other Linux variants is a completely different command).

Comment: @Gilles I was thinking more about the first version, particularly since there's nothing in the question as asked about renaming files. The original (grace period edited) version of this answer had only the `rename` command suggestion.